# How to allow duplicate admin name values for color attribute in magento 2.3

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, duplicate

As per Magento 2.3, it won't allow adding duplicate values for product attributes.

For the temporary purpose, I want to allow the duplicate value of Admin, under color attribute.

How can I restrict the condition programmatically?
in which file should I restrict the condition for duplication?